# toString() unavailable error in Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tostring

While stepping through a method using the Eclipse debugger, I started seeing "toString() unavailable - no suspended threads" for all the variables I wanted to inspect.

Why did I get that error, and what should I do next to narrow down the problem in my code?

**edit** My code does create a new process, but the variables I wanted to examine exist in the main application thread, and that thread didn't appear dead (in the Debug panel or the Console).

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a few scenarios when a method (in particular, `toString()`) would be unavailable:

- When the execution is suspended by pressing the "Suspend" button (the one with the "pause" icon), as opposed to reaching a breakpoint.
- When you've reached a breakpoint, and you're in the middle of evaluating an expression.

In any case, even with `toString()` unavailable, you should be able to inspect the current values in the upper part of the "Variables" view.

Also, try looking at the relevant preferences (Window → Preferences → Java → Debug), in particular the ones under "Detail Formatters". You can also try the "Restore Defaults" button.

Comment: After some more experimentation, I'm fairly certain that I'm somehow in the middle of evaluating an expression during this breakpoint... though I never figured out exactly WHY =)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in early versions of Eclipse 3.1: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=81249

Try upgrading your Eclipse?

Comment: Ooh yeah, forgot to mention that I'm using Eclipse 3.4.